# How to find running balance Month over Month with fixed PMT Values

Tags: microsoft-excel

Please Help. On a Workbook for tuition PTMs from Jan. to Dec., how to calculate outstanding balance so that February balance will be
the result of Ending balance of January, Minus amount paid in February, and repeat it for all remaining months or until its paid off. Thanks for Helping

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: I apologize I am not being to add and Image to try illustrate what I want to do. I was able to format it to calculate the balance, but not to subtract month by month payments.. I appreciate your time, as I know it is valuable. tkx.

Comment: The data reference of the formula may refer to the structure of the table and the definition of the data.To better help you, it is recommended to provide a non-real sample. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You should really post data and how your columns appear. Also, no idea how you want to represent data. But this should solve your problems...

```
Cell C3 Formula: =C2-B3
```

Drag it down and you're done.

[image]